# How do I install GTKWave on Windows?

Tags: gtk, vhdl, verilog, simulator

I am desperately trying to install GTKWave on my Windows machine. Can anyone give me so tips or redirect me to a good tutorial (or even better, post a small tutorial here)?

I think the documentation is not very up to date since it says that GTKWave is available via Cygwin, which it isn't.

Comment: The first link from a quick Google for "gtkwave windows" leads to here:

http://www.dspia.com/gtkwave.html

Comment: @Martin Thompson hey, thank you. I already tried that but I can't get it working. What exactly do I have to do there? Which files do I have to place where?

Comment: Ahh.  I assumed it would just work. Sorry!  Do you need GTKWave specifically, or would any old VCD viewer work?

Comment: Well, isnt GTKWave the only free one?

Comment: I'm sure there's others: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=free+vcd+viewer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb

Comment: `apt-get install gtkwave` https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P488 :-) (not really because GUI is unsupported yet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem once. To make it work you should have Cygwin or MinGW installed on your system. Download GTKWave and `all_libs` from  dspia.com/gtkwave.html as Martin Thompson suggested. Then unzip everything into the same folder. The important thing to make it run under Windows is to put the executable `gtkwave.exe` into the subfolder `all_libs/bin` (this is were all the .dlls are located) or to add it to your path. This way I could make GTKWave run under Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

Binaries for current versions can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkwave/files/

Answer (score 0):

With login, I'm able to download "standalone" Windows executables from the GTKWave github project Actions page [here](https://github.com/gtkwave/gtkwave/actions).